# How to use regex to validate a string key=value format?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String as shown below in `key=value` format:

```
abc=123,111,234
```

It will always be in this format only. Meaning key will always be `abc` string, and value will be numbers followed by comma. I need to validate this format and if it is not in this format, then I need to return false otherwise return true.

I can split a string on `=` and do checks like that to validate it. But can I use regex here? If yes, can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, here's a simple regex to extract key and value and validate the general format:

```
^abc=((?:\d+,)*\d+)$
```

The value in the 1st capture group.

Comment: I want to validate my whole string should be in that format only. key should be String `abc` and value should be numbers followed by comma.

Comment: What is your "whole string" - one line or multiple lines each with this format?

Comment: Just that one line with that format so my String is `abc=123,111,234`

Comment: Ah, you literally mean `abc`, not any identifier made of characters... see edit

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should be more clear. How will I use this in Java to validate the string?

Comment: With the `Pattern` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html